# Solution for $\frac{a}{x} = \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{\left(f(x)+f(z)\right)^2} dz$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the function $f(x)$ that solves $\frac{a}{x}  = \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{\left(f(x)+f(z)\right)^2} dz$ such that $f(0)=0$. Even hints how to approach to this question would be very helpful.

Comment: Don't you think a plausible first step might be to differentiate that sucker?

Comment: Could you specify some hypothesis on $f$ please ? is it supposed to be $C^1$ for example ?

Comment: My conjecture is that f(x) should be strictly increasing and continuous.

Comment: Another clarification, in my application $x \in [0,1]$, so that $f$ is defined only in this interval.